# How to pass value on Button click (Fragment 1) to onCreateView (Fragment 2)?

Tags: android, fragment

I have 2 `Fragments`.
When I click a button in `Fragment 1` here what I do:

1. I set the variable `String title = "Lady Gaga"`.
2. I will show the `Fragment 2`.

When the `Fragment 2` is shown, I want to display the title text.

How to do it?

Comment: Use the singleton pattern to pass the data string

Comment: have you checked the docs. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use bundles to pass data :

```
            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("title", "my title");
            Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
            fragment2.setArguments(data);
            FragmentTransaction agm_ft = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            agm_ft.replace(R.id.frag_containor, fragment2,
                    "agm_frag");
            agm_ft.addToBackStack(null);
            agm_ft.commit();
```

and get it back on next fragment:

```
    Bundle getData = getArguments();
    title = getData.getString("title");
```

Comment: im having a problem in getSupportFragmentManager(). the error said "cannot find symbol getSupportFragmentManager". i am using fragment and my main is Activity.

Comment: im having a problem in getSupportFragmentManager(). the error said "cannot find symbol getSupportFragmentManager". i am using fragment and my main is Activity.

Comment: use FragmentTransaction agm_ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a `Interface`

```
public interface TitleChangeListener {
    public void onUpdateTitle(String title);
}
```

2) in `Fragment 2`

Create a `public` method

```
public void setTitle(String title){
    //Do Somthing
   }
```

3)Let `Activity` implement `Interface TitleChangeListener` and override `onUpdateTitle`

```
 public void onUpdateTitle(String title){
  fragment2.setTitle(title);
 }
```

4) In Button `onClickListner` , 1st `Fragment`

```
   TitleChangeListener listener=(TitleChangeListener)getActivity();
   listener.onUpdateTitle("Lady Gaga");
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting string from one fragment to another you have to use bundles and set them to as arguments like :

```
//on button click

String title = "Lady Gaga";

        Fragment fr = new Final_Categories_Fragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putString("title", title);
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

                .add(R.id.list_frame, fr, "last").commit();
        fr.setArguments(b);

//Now on another fragment you have to get this argument 
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_child_category_listview,
                container, false);
        ...

    String  title = getArguments().getString("title");
    ...
        return rootView;
    }
```